# VS 2010 - #pragma comment (lib, XX) works, Additional Dependencies doesn't. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++, pragma

It seems that no matter what I do, I can't get the Additional Dependencies to properly link my static library.

This static library is created from another project I made. I've tried adding it as a reference, forcing project dependencies, double checking that the path to the lib is correct. The only thing that seems to make my unresolved external linker errors disappear is a #pragma comment (lib, XX).

Does anyone know why this is? I'd very much like to avoid the #pragma comment and just have it added as an additional dependency.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give more details... Are you setting the path to the libraries correctly?

Comment: In Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories, I have properly set the relative path of where the built .lib file resides.

Comment: Are you using debug or release? Are you sure you are separating the lib by `;`

Comment: This is dbg, 32 bit. I am building an executable which links to a static library. The library is similarly built dbg, 32 bit. The libraries are separated by a ;.

Comment: My guess is your relative path is wrong.

Comment: I have another executable project which is at the same level as my executable project which is linking to a different static library which is at the same level as my static library project.

This other project works without a project. They are both building to the same place.

Comment: 'VC++ Directories ' is the wrong place to go. You probably need 'configuration properties/linker/general/additional library directories'.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing: make sure that the project which make the lib got built first, i.e. make sure that the libraries are already created before linking your project.